# How to get boto3 to display _all_ RDS instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto3

Trying to get all *RDS instances* with `boto3` - does not return all RDS instances.

When I look at my RDS instances in Oregon (us-west-2), I see the following:

[image: RDS instances in Oregon]

However, if I run the below Python3 script, I only get one result:

```
$ python3 ./stackoverflow.py 

RDS instances in Oregon
------------------------------
aurora-5-7-yasmin.cazdggrmkpt1.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com qa test db.t2.small aurora-5-7-yasmin
$
```

**Can you suggest a way to get boto3 to display *all* RDS instances?**

---

```
$ cat ./stackoverflow.py 
import collections
import boto3
import datetime
import pygsheets

REGIONS = ('us-west-2',)
REGIONS_H = ('Oregon',)

currentDT = str(datetime.datetime.now())


def create_spreadsheet(outh_file, spreadsheet_name = "AWS usage"):
    client = pygsheets.authorize(outh_file=outh_file, outh_nonlocal=True)
    client.list_ssheets(parent_id=None)
    spread_sheet = client.create(spreadsheet_name)
    return spread_sheet


def rds_worksheet_creation(spread_sheet):
    for i in range(len(REGIONS)):
        region = REGIONS[i]
        region_h = REGIONS_H[i]
        print()
        print("{} instances in {}".format("RDS", region_h))
        print("------------------------------")

        client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
        db_instances = client.describe_db_instances()
        for i in range(len(db_instances)):
            j = i - 1
            try:
                DBName = db_instances['DBInstances'][j]['DBName']
                MasterUsername = db_instances['DBInstances'][0]['MasterUsername']
                DBInstanceClass = db_instances['DBInstances'][0]['DBInstanceClass']
                DBInstanceIdentifier = db_instances['DBInstances'][0]['DBInstanceIdentifier']
                Endpoint = db_instances['DBInstances'][0]['Endpoint']
                Address = db_instances['DBInstances'][0]['Endpoint']['Address']
                print("{} {} {} {} {}".format(Address, MasterUsername, DBName, DBInstanceClass,
                DBInstanceIdentifier))
            except KeyError:
                continue


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spread_sheet = create_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_name = "AWS usage", outh_file = '../client_secret.json')
    spread_sheet.link(syncToCloud=False)
    rds_worksheet_creation(spread_sheet)

$ cat ../client_secret.json 
{"installed":{"client_id":"362799999999-uml0m2XX4v999999mr2s03XX9g8l9odi.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"amiable-shuttle-198516","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"XXXXxQH434Qg-xxxx99_n0vW","redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}}
$
```

### Edit 1:

Following Michael's comment, I changed the script to the following, but even though one more related line appeared, most of the RDS instances are still not returned:

```
$ python3 ./stackoverflow.py 

RDS instances in Oregon
------------------------------
aurora-5-7-yasmin.cazdggrmkpt1.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com qa +++ DBName gave KeyError +++ db.t2.small aurora-5-7-yasmin
aurora-5-7-yasmin.cazdggrmkpt1.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com qa test db.t2.small aurora-5-7-yasmin
$ 

$ cat ./stackoverflow.py 
import collections
import boto3
import datetime
import pygsheets

REGIONS = ('us-west-2',)
REGIONS_H = ('Oregon',)

currentDT = str(datetime.datetime.now())


def create_spreadsheet(outh_file, spreadsheet_name = "AWS usage"):
    client = pygsheets.authorize(outh_file=outh_file, outh_nonlocal=True)
    client.list_ssheets(parent_id=None)
    spread_sheet = client.create(spreadsheet_name)
    return spread_sheet


def rds_worksheet_creation(spread_sheet):
    for i in range(len(REGIONS)):
        region = REGIONS[i]
        region_h = REGIONS_H[i]
        print()
        print("{} instances in {}".format("RDS", region_h))
        print("------------------------------")

        client = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
        db_instances = client.describe_db_instances()
        for i in range(len(db_instances)):
            j = i - 1
            try:
                DBName = db_instances['DBInstances'][j]['DBName']
            except KeyError:
                DBName = "+++ DBName gave KeyError +++"
            MasterUsername = db_instances['DBInstances'][0]['MasterUsername']
            DBInstanceClass = db_instances['DBInstances'][0]['DBInstanceClass']
            DBInstanceIdentifier = db_instances['DBInstances'][0]['DBInstanceIdentifier']
            Endpoint = db_instances['DBInstances'][0]['Endpoint']
            Address = db_instances['DBInstances'][0]['Endpoint']['Address']
            print("{} {} {} {} {}".format(Address, MasterUsername, DBName, DBInstanceClass,
            DBInstanceIdentifier))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spread_sheet = create_spreadsheet(spreadsheet_name = "AWS usage", outh_file = '../client_secret.json')
    spread_sheet.link(syncToCloud=False)
    rds_worksheet_creation(spread_sheet)
```

Comment: Are you masking a problem with `except KeyError:
                continue`?

Comment: @Michael, see *Edit 1.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `for` loop range is getting the value of 2 since `db_instances`is `dict` type.

Instead of

```
for i in range(len(db_instances)):
```

It should be

```
for i in range(len(db_instances['DBInstances'])):
```

Which gives `list` type and correct length to iterate the loop.

Answer (score 12):

You have an error in your original code but if you want this code to scale to a large number of instances (it is unlikely you'll need this) then you'll want to use something like the following:

```
import boto3
available_regions = boto3.Session().get_available_regions('rds')

for region in available_regions:
    rds = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
    paginator = rds.get_paginator('describe_db_instances').paginate()
    for page in paginator:
        for dbinstance in page['DBInstances']:
            print("{DBInstanceClass}".format(**dbinstance))
```

You can get rid of the paginator and just use the first loop if you know each region will have fewer than 100s of instances:

```
for region in available_regions:
    rds = boto3.client('rds', region_name=region)
    for dbinstance in rds.describe_db_instances():
        print("{DBInstanceClass}".format(**dbinstance))
```

Additionally you can provide a simple

```
dbinstance.get('DBName', 'No Name Set')
```

instead of excepting around the KeyError.

Comment: Thanks for the `for region in available_regions:` suggestion. Is there a way in boto3 to convert AWS region codes to AWS region names, e.g to convert `('us-west-1', 'us-east-1', 'us-west-2')` to `('N. California', 'N. Virginia', 'Oregon')`?

Comment: I wanted to see paginator example and this helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This Code will list all RDS instances present in the account

Try this 100 % working code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
client = boto3.client('rds')
response = client.describe_db_instances()
for i in response['DBInstances']:
   db_name = i['DBName']
   db_instance_name = i['DBInstanceIdentifier']
   db_type = i['DBInstanceClass']
   db_storage = i['AllocatedStorage']
   db_engine = i['Engine']
   print db_instance_name,db_type,db_storage,db_engine
```

Answer (score 4):

FYI, the more Pythonic way to do loops in this case would be:

```
for instance in db_instances['DBInstances']:
    MasterUsername = instance['MasterUsername']
    DBInstanceClass = instance['DBInstanceClass']
    etc.
```

This avoids the need for `i`-type iterators.